# Function of assigning empty state in the react component constructor

Tags: reactjs

I've found some old code where they used to assign empty state in the constructor. Does this have any function or entire constructor can be deleted? Since there isn't any other code, I don't see any point having a constructor.

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {};
    }

    render() {
        return (<div title={this.state.title}></div>);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes you can delete, if that code is not adding any key value pair in the state dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Cannot read property 'title' of null"

`this.state == null` if you don't define it.

Therefore, applying a default value to `state` does make a difference if you want to safely reference any sub properties, without checking they exist.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor can be safely deleted since you aren't initialising any state value and using it only after it has been initialised. For you it is still required as you use state in render. You only need to use constructor when you want to initialise certain state values or class variables. However with `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties` plugin, you can specify state as a class object itself like

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component{
    state = { isVisible: true };
}
```

Comment: Updated the code a little. I got error "Cannot read property 'title' of null" when constructor is removed.

Comment: In your code you are using state before initialising it and hence it gives you an error.